# Appilcation of Stokes

Tags: vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

> Prove that a necessary and sufficient condition that $\int_C\vec{F}$
> $\cdot d\vec{r} = 0 $ for every closed curve  C lying in a simply
> connected region R is that $\nabla \times F= 0 $  identically .

Sufficient part is straight forward application of Stokes theorem .
For the necessary part , lets try to prove it by contradiction.If we assume that $\nabla \times F $is not $0$ at some point in the space . By continuity , i think that we can ensure that there exists a neighbourhood where $\nabla \times F $ is not $0$ . Can we then say that there **'definitely'** exists a surface in that neighbourhood where the flux is non-zero . Intuition says that we can , but can we prove it more rigourously ! ?

Comment: I guess that essentially, you need to show that there exists a simply connected surface $S$ with $C^1$ boundary such that $\int_S \vec\nabla\times \vec F\cdot\mathrm d\vec S\neq0$. Maybe use a flat surface containing the point you mention, which is perpendicular to $\vec\nabla\times\vec F$ at that point, then use continuity of $\vec\nabla\times\vec F\cdot \vec n$ (which is a nonzero number at the point) to find a small disc centered at the point over which the integral doesn't vanish?

Comment: Yes , i think i got that . There always is a disc in a neighbourhood . Why am i so dumb ?